# using a resource with for_each and a list of strings for a single string entry in resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create loadbalancer target group attachments via a for_eah approach to safe myself a lot of coding time. However I can't seem to use a for_each in a for_each. Does anyone have a pointer on this?

---

Additional explanation:

The resource **aws_lb_target_group_attachment** only accepts a single target_id in the form of a string, pointing to an instance ID.

So in this case I would like the resource to be created twice. Once for each target_id in the list of target_ids.

---

```
locals {
  dev_alb_defaults = {
    vpc_id      = local.dev_alb_vpc_id
    health_check_enabled              = true
    health_check_interval             = 30
    health_check_timeout              = 5
    health_check_healthy_threshold    = 2
    health_check_unhealthy_threshold  = 2
    health_check_matcher              = 200
  }

  dev_alb_targets = {
    i-am-service = {
      tg_port = 443
      target_ids = [ "i-0123456789ab", "i-0123456789bc" ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "dev_lb_tg" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.dev_alb_targets : k => v }

  name     = "${var.customer}-${var.dev_prefix}-${try(each.value.name, each.key)}-tg"
  port     = try(each.value.tg_port, null)
  protocol = try(each.value.tg_protocol, null)
  vpc_id   = try(each.value.vpc_id,local.dev_alb_defaults.vpc_id, null)

  health_check {
    enabled             = try(each.value.health_check_enabled, local.dev_alb_defaults.health_check_enabled, false)
    path                = try(each.value.health_check_path, local.dev_alb_defaults.health_check_path, null)
    port                = try(each.value.health_check_port, each.value.tg_port, null)
    protocol            = try(each.value.health_check_protocol, local.dev_alb_defaults.health_check_protocol, null)
    interval            = try(each.value.health_check_interval, local.dev_alb_defaults.health_check_interval, null)
    timeout             = try(each.value.health_check_timeout, local.dev_alb_defaults.health_check_timeout, null)
    healthy_threshold   = try(each.value.health_check_healthy_threshold, local.dev_alb_defaults.health_check_healthy_threshold, null)
    unhealthy_threshold = try(each.value.health_check_unhealthy_threshold, local.dev_alb_defaults.health_check_unhealthy_threshold, null)
    matcher             = try(each.value.health_check_matcher, local.dev_alb_defaults.health_check_matcher, null)
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "dev_lb_tg" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.dev_alb_targets : k => v }

  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.dev_lb_tg["${try(each.value.name, each.key)}"].arn
  port             = try(each.value.tg_port, null)
  target_id        = try(each.value.target_ids, null)
  }
}
```

The effect I hoped it had is: creating only 1 target group and creating 2 aws_lb_target_group_attachments. It creates 1 target group, however it does not create 2 target group attachments. I've tried variants in which I used tolist() for tg_instances or tostring()
However I can't get it to accept the input.

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on dev-alb.tf line 288, in resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "dev_lb_tg":
│  288:   target_id        = each.value.target_ids
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.target_ids is list of string with 2 elements
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "target_id": string required.
╵
```

---

Intermediate solution I have right now, which I don't like to use and I would like to condense to a proper solution:

```
locals {
  dev_alb_defaults = {
    target_id1 = "i-0123456789ab"
    target_id2 = "i-0123456789bc"
  }
  dev_alb_targets = {
    i-am-service = {
      tg_port = 443
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "dev_lb_tg1" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.dev_alb_targets : k => v }

  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.dev_lb_tg["${try(each.value.name, each.key)}"].arn
  port             = try(each.value.tg_port, null)
  target_id        = local.dev_alb_defaults.target_id1
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "dev_lb_tg2" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.dev_alb_targets : k => v }

  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.dev_lb_tg["${try(each.value.name, each.key)}"].arn
  port             = try(each.value.tg_port, null)
  target_id        = local.dev_alb_defaults.target_id2
  }
}
```

---

Comment: I don't see tha `target_ids` anywhere in your locals. Is that a previous error?

Comment: What is `target_ids`? Sadly your question is not clear and lacks deatils.

Comment: Sorry, let me correct this.. tg_instances and target_ids are the same. I mixed up the naming on my end writing the article.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **flatten** you local variable:

```
locals {
  dev_alb_targets = {
    i-am-service = {
      tg_port = 443
      target_ids = [ "i-0123456789ab", "i-0123456789bc" ]
    }
  }
  
  flat_dev_alb_targets = merge([
        for service, details in local.dev_alb_targets: {
          for target in details.target_ids:
            "${service}-${target}" => {
               tg_port = details.tg_port
               target_id = target
            }
        }
      ]...) # no NOT remove the dots 
}
```

then

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "dev_lb_tg" {
  for_each         = local.flat_dev_alb_targets

  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.dev_lb_tg["${try(each.value.name, each.key)}"].arn
  port             = try(each.value.tg_port, null)
  target_id        = try(each.value.target_id, null)
  }
}
```

Also your code does not show what `each.value.name` is, so its difficult to speculate on full aspects and requirements on how to flatten it.

Comment: ty @marcin. The ```each.value.name``` is actually pointing back to the map name. So in this case it would be "i-am-service".

So what I'm worried about is, that this flat my cause the other parts of the code causing duplicate creation as well.

I left this out of the question because I thought it was irrelevant. Let me edit it in to give a more complete picture.

Comment: I've added the aws_lb_target_group in there as well. Now I'm afraid (not tested yet) that this flat will create 2 target groups and 2 target group attachments.